# rally SDK 2.1 iteration start date filter won't match greater than

Tags: sdk, rally

I have a cardboard that shows stories in an Epic mapped into iterations, and I want to filter for a selected iteration and all future iterations beyond it.

I have this filter (date hardcoded for now):

```
  var iterFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
    property: 'Iteration.StartDate',
    operation: '>=',
    value: '2018-09-24'
  });
```

But it's only working as an equals. So if I hardcode the date to the start date of an iteration I get stories in that iteration only, no future stories. If I set it to a date that is not the start of an iteration I get nothing at all. If I switch >= to > I get nothing at all. Seems like the > is ignored. Have I got the syntax wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change operation to operator and I think you've got it.

```
{
    property: 'Iteration.StartDate',
    operator: '>=',
    value: '2018-09-24'
}
```